# Using the Rally REST API, how to query and return a *complete* JSON object?

Tags: c#, .net, rally

I'm using the .NET API. By complete, I mean a JSON like this [one](http://pmd2013.gaia.feralhosting.com/last.json) (formatted already, I think it is needed credentials to see it [inside the webservice](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.40/hierarchicalrequirement/11099498122.js)).

It is just a matter of adding more fields to fetch when I instantiate the `Request` object?

```
Request storyRequest = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement")
        {
            /* Fields to Fetch*/
            Fetch = new List<string>() { "Name", "FormattedID", "Children", "Owner", "ScheduleState" }, 
            // keep adding field here...

            /* Add a query - quering the US with ID equals to '_formattedID'*/
            Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, _formattedID)
        };
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT
I would like to query by the user story ID, just in case it is not clear.

Comment: I guess it is just a matter of leaving the Fetch empty... Fetch = new List<string>() {}; sorry for dummy question

Comment: Good find! Would you be willing to add your Comment as an Answer? That way it's easier for others to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building a request, you should filter the field you want to fetch in the Fetch property.

The keys:

```
_rallyAPIMajor
_rallyAPIMinor
_ref
_objectVersion
_refObjectName
```

Are always return by any request. You can leave the Fetch empty, and return all 45 keys (45 for "hierarchicalrequirement") or you can filter the ones you need.